# How to tell which property differs when assertEquals fails (Kotlin data class)?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, junit5

I have a test comparing two objects from the `Client` data class:

```
assertEquals(expectedClient, returnedClient)
```

When I get an error (red state), it's a bit annoying to find the different property:

```
Expected <Client(id=1, firstName=Hodor, lastName=Door, type=MAIN, importer=123, orderNumber=VALID, year=2020)>, actual <Client(id=1, firstName=Hodor, lastName=Door, type=MAIN, importer=124, orderNumber=VALID, year=2020)>.
```

In this case, it was `importer` property... but it's time consuming. And I have data classes with more properties which makes me waste lots of time.

Considering the default implementation of `equals` data classes in Kotlin (compares each property), is there any library to visually compare them like in a table (like what's done in [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) when a test fails)?
Alternatively, I just want an error that says: `these are the different properties: importer`.

Comment: https://github.com/bnorm/kotlin-power-assert can help, maybe (or be extended to help)?